# woocommerce custom add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a project where customers can buy a product or send it as a gift. In the product page I need two buttons, one for buy and the other one for gift. Clicking one of the two buttons, it will add the product to the cart, then in the cart I have to distinguish which one is a buy product and which one is a gift product.

The problem is that I am not able to catch which one of the two buttons is clicked and how to keep this value (and where) and show it in the cart.

Any idea?

thanks

Comment: Please add the code that you've tried so far to your post.

Comment: https://nicola.blog/2015/09/18/creating-custom-add-to-cart-url/ you can read about how an add to Cart button works there. They use a URL parameter to add to the cart that I assume is grabbed on the checkout page. You could also pass in to the URL ?type=gift  or something like that if you are familiar with URL parameters and sending data. You can read about that here http://endlessgeek.com/2014/02/wordpress-pass-extra-variable-url-parameter/

Comment: I haven't write any code so far, I went through the source code in order to understand how to implement this. 
@AlexRindone thanks for your suggestions. My problem is how to add this URL parameter to the cart button added with the shortcode, in other words, how can I add ?type=gift to the URL when the gift button is clicked?

Comment: The second link I sent you will help. It's pretty basic and easy to follow. You'll be modifying the checkout.php file most likely which will have a function to get the URL parameter. As far as the button goes, it's as simple as adding that to the link. Read through the link I sent you and let me know if you have questions. But without code we can only really give you resources to start coding something.